# How to define a composite key, with EF 7, in F#

Tags: entity-framework, f#

I want to replicate this, from C#:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleFeature>().HasKey(vf=> new {vf.VehicleId, vf.FeatureId});
}
```

to F#.

The one solution I had found on this site was:

```
fun x -> (x.VehicleId, x.FeatureId) :> obj)
```

which doesn't work.